# Get maximum pairs without repetition of dictrionary key

Tags: python

I’m struggling with getting maximum utilisation (**"paring"**) of my list.

I have a list of dictionaries where I would like to get maximum number of **"pares"** as long as a given **k2** is not matching. I guess some sort of permutation whitch shrinking resource list?

This is where I got:

```
t = [ {'k1': 1, 'k2': 'a'},
      {'k1': 2, 'k2': 'a'},
      {'k1': 3, 'k2': 'b'},
      {'k1': 4, 'k2': 'b'},
      {'k1': 5, 'k2': 'c'},
      {'k1': 6, 'k2': 'd'},
      {'k1': 7, 'k2': 'a'},
      {'k1': 8, 'k2': 'd'}]

t2 = t[:]

for d in t2:
    for x in t2:
        if d['k2'] != x['k2']:
            print(d,x)
            t2.remove(x)
            t2.remove(d)
            break
```

The problem is that I’m left with `t2 = [{'k2': 'd', 'k1': 6}, {'k2': 'd', 'k1': 8}]`

Which is a **waste of 1 pair**.
**Manually** I can achieve something like:

```
({'k2': 'a', 'k1': 1}, {'k2': 'b', 'k1': 3})
({'k2': 'b', 'k1': 4}, {'k2': 'a', 'k1': 2})
({'k2': 'd', 'k1': 6}, {'k2': 'c', 'k1': 5})
({'k2': 'a', 'k1': 7}, {'k2': 'd', 'k1': 8})
```

or similar with **total of 4 pairs**. am I missing a trick here?

**UPDATE**

What I need is that every time a pair is created I need to remove the items from the list, thus I can get only 4 paris doing this manually.

I don't "care" about the paris as long as k2 doesn't match and I have obtained the **most efficinet** list of pairs i.e. in my code above I **wasted** 1 possible pair by not using dictionary with **k2: d** thus this was not the most efficient combination.

I do appologise if this is still not clear, perhaps I'm presenting it wrong.

Comment: Please provide your expected output.

Comment: I just need to know that from a given list of dict, I can get x number of pairs. i.e. in the example above I can get to 4 pairs(manually)., the only requirement is that the **k2** is not repeted in the "pair". The output can be a tuplet or a list, i.e. `({'k2': 'a', 'k1': 7}, {'k2': 'b', 'k1': 3})`, I'll update the question

Comment: So why isn't `(d,a)` a valid pair? Or `(b, c)`? There are a lot more than 4 combinations here. Your question is _very_ vague.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, Yes I'm aware of that but I don't "care" about the paris as long as `k2` doesn't  match and I have obtained the **most efficinet** list of pairs i.e. in my code above I wasted 1 possible pair by not using dictionary with  `k2: d`.

Comment: As an aside it's generally not a good idea to mutate the collection you're iterating over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the maximum number of possible pairs, you have to create the pairs in a smart way. Consider an input like this:

```
k2_values = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'b']
```

If you don't care to build the pairs correctly, you might end up pairing `a` and `c`, which would prevent you from creating a 2nd pair because you only have 2 `b`s left. To get the maximum number of pairs, you have to start building pairs with those values that you have the most of - with `b`.

Thus, the first step is to group your list of dicts by the `k2` value:

```
{'a': [{'k1': 1, 'k2': 'a'}, {'k1': 2, 'k2': 'a'}, {'k1': 7, 'k2': 'a'}],
 'b': [{'k1': 3, 'k2': 'b'}, {'k1': 4, 'k2': 'b'}],
 'c': [{'k1': 5, 'k2': 'c'}],
 'd': [{'k1': 6, 'k2': 'd'}, {'k1': 8, 'k2': 'd'}]}
```

Then sort those groups by length:

```
[[{'k1': 1, 'k2': 'a'}, {'k1': 2, 'k2': 'a'}, {'k1': 7, 'k2': 'a'}],
 [{'k1': 3, 'k2': 'b'}, {'k1': 4, 'k2': 'b'}],
 [{'k1': 6, 'k2': 'd'}, {'k1': 8, 'k2': 'd'}],
 [{'k1': 5, 'k2': 'c'}]]
```

And finally build pairs from these groups.

---

### Implementation

```
import operator
import collections

def make_pairs(dicts, keyfunc):
    if isinstance(keyfunc, str):
        keyfunc = operator.itemgetter(keyfunc)

    # group the dicts by k2 values
    grouped_dicts = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for dic in dicts:
        key = keyfunc(dic)
        grouped_dicts[key].append(dic)

    # sort the groups by size
    grouped_dicts = sorted(grouped_dicts.values(), key=len, reverse=True)

    # iterate over the groups and build pairs
    iters = [(len(group), iter(group)) for group in grouped_dicts]
    iters_itr = iter(iters)

    len1, itr1 = next(iters_itr)
    for len2, itr2 in iters_itr:
        # make sure the shorter iterator comes first
        if len1 > len2:
            itr1, itr2 = itr2, itr1
            len1, len2 = len2, len1

        yield from zip(itr1, itr2)

        # discard the exhausted iterator and re-calculate
        # the remaining length
        itr1 = itr2
        len1 = len2 - len1
```

Test run:

```
>>> list(make_pairs(t, 'k2'))
[({'k1': 3, 'k2': 'b'}, {'k1': 1, 'k2': 'a'}),
 ({'k1': 4, 'k2': 'b'}, {'k1': 2, 'k2': 'a'}),
 ({'k1': 7, 'k2': 'a'}, {'k1': 6, 'k2': 'd'}),
 ({'k1': 8, 'k2': 'd'}, {'k1': 5, 'k2': 'c'})]
```

Comment: I liked both answers the long(first) one as you were explaining all of the steps, and the short(last) as it was more compressed, although for me more difficult to understand since I'm not that advanced in python.I guess `iters = [(len(group), iter(group)) for group in grouped_dicts]` this is list comperhension?
In the last answer I had to to use `for l in zip(itr1, itr2): yield l` as I'm on python 2 but that's not an issue ;)
Anyway, do you mind puting both of the versions of you answer, as next person may find it equaly helpfull ;)

Comment: @MMT I'd rather not. It was way too nested and unintuitive and generally not very good code. But I can at least leave a link to the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50133528/1), in case someone really wants to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Though I'm not entirely sure, this has the feel of a [bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). Your bins can accommodate 2 items with unique value by some definition. The problem statement is then to minimize the amount of used bins, or in other words avoid producing bins containing just 1 item, if possible.

Implementing a [first-fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#First-fit_algorithm) approximate solution is rather straightforward. It will not produce perfect results for all values, but it just so happens that it does find the optimal solution for yours:

```
def pairs(t, key):
    bins = []
    full = []

    for d in t:
        for i, (k, p) in enumerate(bins):
            if d[key] != k:
                p.append(d)
                full.append(p)
                # This is okay only because we do not continue
                # iterating after mutation.
                del bins[i]
                break

        else:
            # No bin could hold this d, so create a new one
            bins.append((d[key], [d]))

    return full
```

As an additional measure you could sort the values by frequency first, making this a sort of a first-fit descending:

```
def pairs(t, key):
    lookup = defaultdict(list)

    for d in t:
        lookup[d[key]].append(d)

    gs = sorted(lookup.values(), key=len, reverse=True)
    ds = [d for g in gs for d in g]

    bins = []
    full = []

    for d in ds:
        ...

    ...
```